# PlotRange adjustments with BarChart

Tags: plotting, charts

I'm working on making some `BarCharts`, however, some of my data is contained within a small range so I want the plot to start above 0 and cut-off the bars below that, however, when I try to use `PlotRange` the bars are not cropped properly (they extend below the axis) and if you try to introduce `ChartLabels` they are cut in half!

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, ChartLabels -> Range[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.2, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.2, 1}}, ChartLabels -> Range[10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried playing around with `ImagePadding` and `BarOrigin` but nothing seems to work. Is there a better solution?

With a `ListPlot` adjusting the `PlotRange`

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, 10], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.2, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but forcing the vertical axis to start at anything other than zero is misleading. See chapter 5 of "How to Lie with Statistics".

Comment: I am not near a Mathematica installation so I can't check, but isn't this fixed using `PlotRangeClipping -> True`?

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I would have to disagree. How is this different than background subtraction. There could be a constant baseline for all the measurements even where one is an "end point".

Comment: s0rce, I saw your (deleted) comment that my method wasn't working, and then the Accept (thanks).  I assume that you had to make some changes to the code to get it to work in your version of *Mathematica*.  Could you tell me what those were, or add them to my answer so that it is more complete?

Comment: By the way, I have no idea why this question has only one vote.  I thought it was quite a good question myself!

Comment: @Verbeia That's part of the solution anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question.  The problem is that the chart labels are placed as `Text` objects inside the `Graphics` body rather than as Ticks along an axis or frame.  Further, the extent of the bars is not limited by the PlotRange.  To get around this we can convert the `Text` labels to `Ticks`.  (Version 7 does not appear to accept `Placed[. . . , Axis]` as shown in kguler's answer or this could likely be simplified.)

Since the format of the output of `BarChart` likely changes between version I shall describe what I am doing so that it can be adapted to other versions.

First I create a chart with additional options to yield the look desired:

```
ch =
 BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10],
  BarSpacing -> Large,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.2, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0},
  PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ChartLabels -> Range@10
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No labels are visible but they are present in the code itself.  There is a `GraphicsGroup` containing a series of `Text` objects of the form:

> ```
> Text[Pane[1], Offset[{0, -2}, {0.5, 0}], ImageScaled[{1/2, 1}]]
> ```

From these we can extract the label information:

```
labels = Cases[ch[[1]], Text[lbl_, Offset[_, {pos_, _}], ___] :> {pos, lbl, 0}, -4];
```

And then add them to the chart as tick labels:

```
Show[ch, Ticks -> {labels, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

#### *Update*

In recent versions of *Mathematica* `BarChart` defaults to `Axes -> {False, True}`; the x axis must be drawn for the Tick labels to be displayed:

```
Show[ch, Ticks -> {labels}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively `Frame` and `FrameTicks` may be used as s0rce shows below.

---

**edit (by s0rce):**

I'm not sure why, but this wasn't working for me as is. However, I almost always use `Frame->True` and when I did that everything worked (with some minor `FrameTicks` and `PlotRangePadding` adjustment).

```
ch = 
 BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], 
  BarSpacing -> Large, 
  Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.2, 1}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  ChartLabels -> Range@10
]

labels = Cases[ch[[1]], 
   Text[lbl_, Offset[_, {pos_, _}], ___] :> {pos, lbl, 0}, -4];

Show[ch, FrameTicks -> {labels, Automatic, False, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: There is an extra comma after `Range@10` in the last code blocl.

Comment: @Art Thanks, I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you mean like this? Will clean this more, just wanted to know if this is what you wanted. If you do not want to move the origin also, you can remove the `AxesOrigin -> {0, z}` from the code

```
Manipulate[

 f[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
  Module[{h = ymax - ymin, t},
   t = If[z >= h, h, z];
   Polygon[{{xmin, ymin + t}, {xmax, ymin + t}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}}]];

 Grid[{
   {
    BarChart[data, BarSpacing -> Large, ImageSize -> 300, 
     ChartElementFunction -> f, PlotRange -> {All, {-5, 5}},AxesOrigin -> {0, z}],

    BarChart[data, BarSpacing -> Large, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotRange -> {All, {-5, 5}}, ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[10], Below], 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
    }}],

 {{z, 0.2, "z="}, 0, 3, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 TrackedSymbols :> {z},
 Initialization :>
  {
   data = RandomReal[{1, 5}, 10];
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I want to chop off the bars at an arbitrary y-value, in this case 0.2 and then move the x-axis up to that point and cut off the bars below. Basically change the y `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 2):

```
modifyF = With[{pl = PlotRange@#}, # /. RectangleBox[{xmin_, 0.}, {xmax_, ymax_}, z___] :> 
  RectangleBox[{xmin, pl[[2, 1]]}, {xmax, Min[pl[[2, 2]], Max[pl[[2, 1]], ymax]]}, z]]&;
```

Example:

```
bc = BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, ImagePadding -> 20,
   ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[10], Axis], PlotRange -> {.2, 1}, ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{bc, modifyF@bc}]
```

[image]