# BarChart with error bars

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, charts

I need to plot `BarChart` with the error bars. What's the most straightforward way to do it?#plot range from 8 to 10 `{8.5,8.6,8.9,9.5}` and error bars of `0.1` and labeling of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.
Is there something like `` "ErrorBarPlots`" `` package which I can use for `BarChart`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.html)?

Comment: @BlacKow yes, But for my simple case, there should be a simple way.

Comment: Your x intervals aren't equal. What about your bars? you want them to have the same width or different width? `ListLinePlot` with `Filling` option?

Comment: @BlacKow x intervals are the same and just labels.

Comment: ` {8.5,8.6,8.9,9.5}` definitely not the same. Do you need these number represented on your plot? Or it will be just four bars labeled a,b,c,d?

Comment: @BlacKow Those are y values and on the x axis I just need lables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how is it simple, but something like this should work. As a bonus you can change bar width.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
prepData[data_, 
  size_] := {{#2 - size/2, 
      0}, {#2 - size/2, #1}, {#2 + size/2, #1}, {#2 + size/2, 0}} & @@@
    MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, data] // Flatten[#, 1] &

data = {{8.5, 8.6, 8.9, 9.5}, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}};

Show[ListLinePlot[prepData[#1, 0.9], Filling -> Axis, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {8, 10}}, 
    Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{First@#2, #1} &, #2], Automatic}], 
   ErrorListPlot@
    MapIndexed[{{First@#2, #1}, ErrorBar[0.1]} &, #1]] & @@ data
```

[image]

Comment: Well done, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {{8.5, 8.6, 8.9, 9.5}, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}};
bcdata = # -> RandomReal[.5] & /@ data[[1]];

bc = BarChart[bcdata, ChartLabels -> Placed[data[[2]], Axis],
 ChartElementFunction -> errorBar[],  PlotRange -> {8, 10}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To crop the bottom of the bars:

```
modifyF@bc
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where the functions [errorBar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61672/125) and [modifyF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19890/125) are

```
errorBar[type_: "Rectangle"][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, 
  meta_] := Block[{error}, error = Flatten[meta];
  error = If[error === {}, 0, Last[error]];
  {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, value, meta], {Black, 
    Line[{{{(x0 + x1)/2, y1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, y1 + error}}, 
         {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 + error}}, 
         {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 - error}}}]}}]

modifyF = With[{pl = PlotRange@#}, # /. RectangleBox[{xmin_, 0.}, {xmax_, ymax_}, z___] :> 
      RectangleBox[{xmin, pl[[2, 1]]}, 
       {xmax, Min[pl[[2, 2]], Max[pl[[2, 1]], ymax]]}, z]] &;
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty straightforward solution, once you spend an hour studying it -- typical for MM. It uses BarChart and the ChartElementFunction option exactly for its intended purpose -- as opposed to turning ListLinePlot into a bar chart and using  an external package.