# Is this a BarChart bug and is there a fix?

Tags: graphics, bugs, charts

Trying to adjust the plot range in bar charts produces an unwanted result where the bars extend below the baseline/below the frame:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {1.0, All}}]
```

[image]

This result interferes with frame labels:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"My Frame Label", None},
 PlotRange -> {All, {1.0, All}}]
```

[image]

And the bottom of the chart is not recognised when chart labels are set to `Bottom` (I had assumed that `Bottom` would be the bottom of the rendered bar).

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
 Frame -> True,
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, Bottom],
 PlotRange -> {All, {1.0, All}}]
```

[image]

Do others agree that this is either a bug or a design flaw and does anyone have any ideas for easy fixes (a fix can be made by writing my own bar chart function from primitives of course)?

**Edit**

Bug confirmed by WRI tech support

Comment: `PlotRangeClipping`? But that doesn't help with the labels.

Comment: @CarlWoll doing that and `Placed[...,Axis]` get close.

Comment: When I remove the PlotRange->[.] option, it works all fine. Note the typo in the title (BarChat).

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [PlotRange adjustments with BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19886/125)

Comment: @kglr yes it is a duplicate. Although there appears to be no solution to get the labels at the bottom of the bars??

Comment: @Mike, so it is **not** a duplicate since the linked question does not  include placement of labels.

Comment: @kglr I've also found that placing labels at Axis doesn't work if you use not default frame ticks (i.e. customised for the y axis)