# Edit BarChart axis?

Tags: graphics, charts

Is there some way to stop the y-axis plotting below the origin in the chart below.  The `PlotRangePadding` is required to make room for the labels, but it pulls the y-axis too low, (as indicated).  The axis graphics don't seem to be editable.

```
data = {{3, 2}, {6, 3}, {8, 10}, {9, 9},
   {3, 1}, {5, 2}, {6, 4}, {7, 8},
   {4, 1}, {7, 2}, {9, 0}, {10, 12}};

bc = BarChart[data, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
   ChartStyle -> {LightOrange, LightGreen}, ImageSize -> 900, AspectRatio -> 0.4,
   ChartLabels -> {Flatten@ConstantArray[{"Mar", "Jun", "Sep", "Dec"}, 3], None},
   ImagePadding -> 8, PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {2, Automatic}}];

labels = MapThread[Inset[Style[#1, Bold, 16], {#2, -1.8}, {Center, Bottom}] &,
   {{"2015", "2016", "2017"}, {6.5, 18.5, 30.5}}];

selopts = {AspectRatio, Axes, AxesOrigin, ImageSize, PlotRangePadding};
opts0 = selopts /. bc[[2]];
opts = Thread[selopts -> opts0];
Graphics[bc[[1]], opts, Epilog -> Append[labels,
   Inset[SwatchLegend[{LightOrange, LightGreen}, Style[#, 12] & /@ {"Masha", "Bear"},
     LegendMarkerSize -> 20, LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4,
         FrameStyle -> Gray] &)], {28, 10.5}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: You asked for that with `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: @Alan - Yes, if `PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}` is used it fixes the y-axis but chops off the year labels.  I might have to use `Labeled` for the year labels but then they are disconnected from the chart.  Not too bad if the chart width is constant though.

Comment: Loosely related question: [PlotRange adjustments with BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19886/plotrange-adjustments-with-barchart/19925#19925)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the options `PlotRangePadding -> Automatic`  and
 `ImagePadding -> {{8, 8}, {50, 8}}` before `opts` in `Graphics` gives

[image]

Comment: Terrific, thanks.